# Get request works but not post request when deploying to Google app engine?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine

Trying to deploy my react express app to GAE and currently my /home route works and serves 'hello Node.js on App engine standard!'. However my post route does not work and it receives a cannot get /post error.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Here is my server.js file

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http')
// const server = http.createServer(app)
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const mailgunTransport = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport')


const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081, ()=>{
  const host = server.address().address
  const port = server.address().port

console.log(`app listening at http://${host}:${port}`);
})

// to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
  })
)

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
res.send('hello Node.js on App engine standard!')

});

app.post('/post', function (req, res) {
  const mailgun = require("mailgun-js");

  const DOMAIN = 'mail';
  const mg = mailgun({apiKey: 'api'
, domain: 'sandbox89eb814ff83548cebd77c0c7d263172e.mailgun.org' });
  const message = {
    from: 'Tom <mail>',
    to: 'mail',
    subject: 'Registration form details',
    html:

    '<h1 style="color:red">Please find new Program orientation registrations details below</h1>' +


    '<p><strong>My Details</strong></p>' +
    '<br> <b>Preferred Name: </b> ' + '' + req.body.fName +
    '<br> <b>Middle Name: </b> ' + '' + req.body.mName +
    '<br> <b>Last Name: </b> ' + '' + req.body.lName +
    '<br> <b>Email Name: </b> ' + '' + req.body.email +


  };

  mg.messages().send(message, function (error, body) {
    console.log(body);
  });

  let data = [
    {
      // page one data
      generalDetails: req.body.generalDetails,
      fName: req.body.fName,
      mName: req.body.mName,
      lName: req.body.lName,
      email: req.body.email,

    }
  ]

  res.json(data)
})


// app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`)
```

App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PageOne from "./components/PageOne";
import PageTwo from "./components/PageTwo";
import PageThree from "./components/PageThree";
import PageFour from "./components/PageFour";
import PageFive from "./components/PageFive";
import PageSix from "./components/PageSix";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
import axios from "axios";



class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fName: "Text",
      lName: "Text",
      gender: "Text",
      email: '',



    };

    this.onContentChange = this.onContentChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmitForm = this.onSubmitForm.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <PageOne handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <PageTwo handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <PageThree handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <PageFour handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <PageFive handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <PageSix handleChange={this.onContentChange} />

        <Button onClick={this.onSubmitForm}
        style={{
          marginLeft: 700,
        }}
        >Submit Form</Button>

        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }

  onSubmitForm = e => {
  e.preventDefault();


}

    var data = {
      fName: this.state.fName,
      mName: this.state.mName,
      lName: this.state.lName,
      email: this.state.email,


    };




    axios
  .post("http://localhost:8081/home", data)
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("Something went wrong. Please try again later");
  });


  };



  //end

  onContentChange(fieldname, data) {
    console.log("On Content Change", data);

    this.setState({
      [fieldname]: data
    });

  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `cannot get /post error` means your server can't handle `GET` request for `/post` route. If you were to test `POST /post` route, then you should use some tools like [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).